# Does the adjective "mute" apply to "Light"?

Tags: phrase-usage, adjectives

I learned the meaning of *mute* is "characterized by an absence of sound; quiet" from [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mute?q=mute). From the above meaning I understand mute is an adjective or attribute which is applicable and related to sound. However I have come across the phrase *muted light* from the below excerpt which is from "The Grave Yard Book" by Neil Gaiman.

> There was moon light, and there were streetlights, but the fog is stifled every thing, *muted light* and muffled sound and made the night shadowy and treacherous.

By that meaning I don't understand how *mute* is applicable to "*light*". I can not imagine what muted light would be. Can *mute* be applicable to the things which are related to *light*?

Answer (score 3):

From the link you provide:

> Verb [with object]
>
> reduce the strength or intensity of: "police violence was always muted by the presence of the media"

*Muted* is the past participle of the verb *mute*, which, as with the past participles of all transitive verbs, can be used where adjectives can be used.

So *muted light* means light that has had its intensity reduced.

Answer (score 1):

*Muted* is an adjective that applies to colors, and lighting; in that case, it means *subdued*.
The OALD (which reports "not bright" as one of the meaning of *muted*, when used for colors, light, etc.) has the following example:

> a dress in muted shades of blue